# JWPlayer not playing on iPad / iPhone when using API load method

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, jwplayer

If I load the video by passing the file at initialisation time, it works:

```
var jw = jwplayer('container').setup({
    width: 528,
    height: 295,
    skin: 'skins/rizla/rizla.xml',
    bufferlength : 0.1,
    modes: [
        {type: 'flash', src: 'jwplayer/player.swf'},
        {type: 'html5'}
    ],
    file : 'http://full/path/to/video.mp4',
});
```

However, if I used the `load` method from the player API, it plays fine in browsers (with Flash disabled so the HTML5 version loads) but won't play on the iPad / iPhone (but with no errors displayed):

```
jw.load({file : 'http://full/path/to/video.mp4'});
```

Examining the results of `jw.getPlaylist()` for each type of loading reveals very different values but that might unrelated to the issue.

Note: The video plays fine when linked to directly, opening in the default media player so it's not a video issue but a jwPlayer-specific issue.

Comment: I think ipad is no flash support?

Comment: Have you tried loading the MP4 directly using the ipad/iphone? Does that work? Just to eliminate a wrongly encoded file as the problem.

Comment: Yes, the video works fine when loaded directly and also works in jwPlayer when loaded in `setup`

Comment: how did you fix this?

Comment: I didn't really fix it, we changed the implementation to re-instantiate the player for each new video, which should not have been required but was a workaround. That was some time ago so jwPlayer may have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work in version 6.0. See js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hRAKQ/4/

```
var jw = jwplayer("test").setup({
    file: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
}); 

$('button').on('click', function() {
    jwplayer("test").load([{
        file: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
        image: "http://lorempixel.com/320/180/"
    }]);
});
```